# AstroPy SkyCoord extremely slow, how to resovle it?

Tags: python, coordinates, data-conversion, astropy

I am using AstroPy SkyCoord to do conversion from equatorial coordinates to galactic coordinates with millions data, it is extremely slow. Anyone has idea to speed it up, otherwise it takes forever to run the whole dataset. The code is below:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import numpy as np

ra1 = np.loadtxt('data.txt',usecols=(0,))
dec1 = np.loadtxt('data.txt',usecols=(1,))
size = len(ra1)
for i in range(size):
    ra = ra1[i]
    dec = dec1[i]
    c = SkyCoord(ra*u.degree, dec*u.degree)
    cc = c.galactic
    b = cc.b.degree
    l = cc.l.degree
```

Comment: How slow is "extremely slow"? Please quantify the amount of data and time it takes. If `ra` and `dec` are your input arrays, this is probably the fastest you can get (unless you code some multiprocessing around it).

Comment: @Evert It takes about an hour to run 180,000 data. But I have more than 5 million. I do not understand why the conversion takes so long to run.

Comment: I can run this fine with `len(c) == 10000000`. You may be running into memory limits of your machine and do a lot of swapping. though 180,000 is really low. What is the memory limit of your machine?

Comment: @Evert The machine I am using is quite powerful. It has 8 processors, total 32 Gb memory. I do not have much swapping in my analysis, I just do the stack of spectra.

Comment: Typical. What type is `ra1` (and what dimension?) and what type is `ra`?

Comment: ra1 is just a 1D python list, ra is pure number. I loop over the whole data, but do the conversion one by one.

Comment: You forgot to show the loop in your example; that misdirected me. Just make sure you have a complete example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: Please show your full code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I loop over the whole data, but do the conversion one by one.

Don't do that. Think vector-wise, just like numpy. Most routines in astropy are meant to be used vector-wise.

Thus:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import numpy as np

c = SkyCoord(np.array(ra1)*u.degree, np.array(dec1)*u.degree)
cc = c.galactic
b = cc.b.degree
l = cc.l.degree
```

and don't loop over it.

`c`, `cc`, `b` and `l` will all be arrays (albeit some are `SkyCoord` arrays), with the same length as `ra1` and `dec1`.

For a 180,000 on your machine, this should take less than a second to run.

---

Hardly ever should you have to run a for-loop *in Python* when your data (list) grows to more than 10,000 or 100,000 elements. Use numpy (or astropy here), or if there is no other option, seek out Cython or even code it in C. (Or use PyPi, but that loses a lot of library compatibilities.)

Python is not fast when looping over (large) lists/arrays, and it was never meant to be.

Comment: It works very well. I did not know this routine is designed to use vector wise, otherwise I will use numpy array. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is unfortunately not mentioned in the astropy coordinate documentation, but only halfway through in the more detailed overview of the [SkyCoord class](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/skycoord.html#array-operations). Perhaps that should be brought forward more into the introduction.

Comment: For what it's worth, if `ra1` and `dec1` in your example are not already arrays, I think it's cleaner and more clear to convert them explicitly to quantities with `u.Quantity('ra1', 'degree')`, etc.  But that's just me.

Comment: So simple, thank you. I didn't know that `SkyCoord` was meant to be used vector-wise either. usually I don't think of object creation in this way. I just sped up my code (which created a `SkyCoord` object 700,000 times, and did some calculations) from 11 hours (estimate) to 43 seconds.... -_-

Comment: @jphollowed That's a lot of coffee you now can't drink anymore while you wait for you results. (By the way, this array style holds for most things in Astropy, for example `Time` as well.)