# Astropy ICRS to Galactocentric transformation Numpy AttributeError

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

i need to convert a large ICRS database (around 1 billion data) to galactocentric coordinates. First, i tried using converting my data to coord.ICRS then transform these to coord.Galactocentric in an iteration loop. But it is very time consuming. Searching around, i [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146183/astropy-skycoord-extremely-slow-how-to-resovle-it) that in coord.Skycoord you can use arrays of data for transformation. So i implemented the solution on my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/data (1).csv')
data_ra = data['ra']
data_dec = data['dec']
data_dist = data['r_est']
data_ra = data_ra * u.degree  
data_dec = data_dec * u.degree  
data_dist = data_dist * u.pc  
c = coord.ICRS(data_ra, data_dec, data_dist)
c = c.transform_to(coord.Galactocentric) 
x = c.x.value
y = c.y.value
z = c.z.value
```

It returns the error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-26-e02bbc9ec5dd> in <module>()
      6 data_dec = data_dec * u.degree
      7 data_dist = data_dist * u.pc
----> 8 c = coord.ICRS(data_ra, data_dec, data_dist)
      9 c = c.transform_to(coord.Galactocentric)
     10 x = c.x.value

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/astropy/units/quantity.py in __new__(cls, value, unit, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
    340                 # Convert all quantities to the same unit.
    341                 if unit is None:
--> 342                     unit = value[0].unit
    343                 value = [q.to_value(unit) for q in value]
    344                 value_unit = unit  # signal below that conversion has been done

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'unit'
```

I can't seem to fix the problem, is coord.ICRS not array compatible? If so, how can i speed up the process of transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This surprised me a bit too.  The reason, though, is that when you access a column of a Pandas `DataFrame`, it doesn't return a plain Numpy array, but rather a Pandas `Series` object (I tested this with some dummy data):

```
>>> data_ra = data['ra']
>>> type(data_ra)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

It seems that (and this feels a bit buggy to me), although you can multiply a `Series` by a unit, it doesn't work properly:

```
>>> data_ra = data_ra * u.degree
>>> type(data_ra)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So rather than getting an Astropy `Quantity` like you would hope, it just gives back a `Series`.  In fact, the `Quantity` *is* still in there, in the `Series`' `.value` attribute:

```
>>> data_ra.values
<Quantity [ 1., 2., 3.] deg>
```

But other things are broken in this case.  What would work better to create `Quantity`s in the first place would be to use the `.values` attribute on each `Series`--this returns a plain Numpy array which can be converted to a `Quantity`:

```
>>> data_ra = df['ra'].values * u.degree
>>> data_dec = data['dec'].values * u.degree
>>> data_dist = data['dist'].values * u.pc
>>> c = coord.ICRS(data_ra, data_dec, data_dist)
>>> c
<ICRS Coordinate: (ra, dec, distance) in (deg, deg, pc)
    [( 1.,  4.,  7.), ( 2.,  5.,  8.), ( 3.,  6.,  9.)]>
>>> c.transform_to(coord.Galactocentric)
<Galactocentric Coordinate (galcen_coord=<ICRS Coordinate: (ra, dec) in deg
    ( 266.4051, -28.936175)>, galcen_distance=8.3 kpc, galcen_v_sun=( 11.1,  232.24,  7.25) km / s, z_sun=27.0 pc, roll=0.0 deg): (x, y, z) in pc
    [(-8300.70096432,  3.76036129,  21.14296691),
     (-8300.99504334,  4.33255373,  20.35548782),
     (-8301.33502602,  4.91092559,  19.5850604 )]>
```

Better still, unless you need to use Pandas for something else, you can also use Astropy to read CSV files and return a `Table` of `Quantity`s in the desired dimensions.  E.g.,

```
>>> t = Table.read('foo.csv')
>>> for col, unit in [('ra', u.degree), ('dec', u.degree), ('dist', u.pc)]:
...     t[col].unit = unit
... 
>>> t
<Table length=3>
 col0   dec     dist     ra  
        deg      pc     deg  
int64 float64 float64 float64
----- ------- ------- -------
    0     4.0     7.0     1.0
    1     5.0     8.0     2.0
    2     6.0     9.0     3.0
>>> coord.ICRS(t['ra'], t['dec'], t['dist'])
<ICRS Coordinate: (ra, dec, distance) in (deg, deg, pc)
    [( 1.,  4.,  7.), ( 2.,  5.,  8.), ( 3.,  6.,  9.)]>
```

It is a little unfortunate that there is no way (that I could find) to specify the column dimensions directly in the `Table.read()` call.  That might make a nice addition to the API.

However, if you write your `Table` back out to an [ECSV](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/write.html#ecsv-format) file, it will save it in a format that is like CSV, but includes additional metadata for reconstructing the table upon reading, including setting the units:

```
>>> t.write('foo.ecsv')
>>> Table.read('foo.ecsv')
<Table length=3>
 col0   dec     dist     ra  
        deg      pc     deg  
int64 float64 float64 float64
----- ------- ------- -------
    0     4.0     7.0     1.0
    1     5.0     8.0     2.0
    2     6.0     9.0     3.0
>>> print(open('foo.ecsv').read())
# %ECSV 0.9
# ---
# datatype:
# - {name: col0, datatype: int64}
# - {name: dec, unit: deg, datatype: float64}
# - {name: dist, unit: pc, datatype: float64}
# - {name: ra, unit: deg, datatype: float64}
# schema: astropy-2.0
col0 dec dist ra
0 4.0 7.0 1.0
1 5.0 8.0 2.0
2 6.0 9.0 3.0
```

Comment: Last night i realized adding .values actually works (not sure if its working properly), but using astropy to import the csv files is actually a good idea, thanks :)